# popover on uitableviewcell à la facebook

Tags: iphone, uitableview, popover

Do you know how to display a popover on UITableViewCell like in the facebook app?

[Here's an iphone screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdVUh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't using UIPopover here. When the cell is tapped you can get the indexPath and use:

```
- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Then you can create a custom UIView and overlay it on top of the UITableView and then in this case they also use a dark transparent layer to help distinguish it from the other content.

src example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...

    CGRect myRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIView * myView = [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,myRect.origin.y + 5,320,300]
    [self.view addSubview:myView];

    ...
}
```